# Is the Hodge class defined on stack or coarse moduli?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces

I understand the definition of the Hodge class on the moduli stack $\mathcal{M}_g$ or $\bar{\mathcal{M}}_g$. However, the Hodge class seems to be used for the coarse moduli space $M_g$ or $\bar{M}_g$ as well. I just don't get this statement. Let me give an example of how this is used: apparently the Hodge class induces a birational map $\bar{M}_g\to X$, where $X$ is projective, whose ramification locus is just the boundary.

More generally, classes that seem to be defined only on the stack are then used to draw consequences on the moduli space. What is the underlying principle?

Comment: The Hodge line bundle does **not** descend to $\bar{M}_g$ -- see *Geometry of algebraic curves* II, by Arbarello-Cornalba-Griffiths, pp. 343-344.

Comment: A nonzero multiple of the Hodge class descends to the coarse moduli space: this is all that is needed to define the map. (In general, the Picard groups of a smooth Deligne--Mumford stack and its coarse moduli space are the same rationally.)